JPA saveAll() throwing classCastException with java version 17 ...works fine with java version 11
`I have  following classes

`@Getter
@Setter
@Slf4j
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = Constant.TABLE_VRT_CONFIG_SYNC_STATUS)
@Convert(attributeName = "jsonb", converter = JsonBinaryType.class)
@Audited(withModifiedFlag = true)
public class VrtConfigSyncStatus implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositeKeyVrtSyncStatus id;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Timestamp createdDate;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "modified_by")
    private String modifiedBy;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "modified_on")
    private Timestamp modifiedDate;

    @Column(name = "hierarchy_id")
    private String hierarchyId;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status = "Y";


    @Column(name = "system_status")`your text`
    private String systemStatus = "Y";

    @Column(name = "metadata", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private JsonNode metadata;

    @Column(name = "cloud_environment")
    private String cloudEnvironment;


    @Column(name = "env_id")
    private String envId;


    @Column(name = "module_id")
    private String moduleId;

    @Column(name = "resource")
    private String resource;


    @Column(name = "action")
    private String action;

    @Column(name = "component_config", columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.JSON)
    private Object componentConfig;

    @Column(name = "component_name")
    private String componentName;

    @Column(name = "component_version")
    private Double componentVersion;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "last_sync_timestamp")
    private Timestamp lastSyncTimestamp;

    @Column(name = "remarks")
    private String remarks;

    @Column(name = "sync_status")
    private String syncStatus;

    @Column(name = "vrt_resolver_type")
    private String vrtResolverType;

    @Column(name = "deployment_history_deployment_id")
    private Integer deploymentHistoryDeploymentId;

    @Column(name = "deployment_history_app_id")
    private String deploymentHistoryAppId;


    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "deployment_history_deployment_id", referencedColumnName = "deployment_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "deployment_history_app_id", referencedColumnName = "app_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    }, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "Fk_VrtConfigSYncStatus_DeploymentHistory"))
    private DeploymentHistory deploymentHistory;





    public VrtConfigSyncStatus(BrmSyncData publishData, TriggerSyncRequestV2 syncRequestV2, HistoryCompositeKey deploymentId) throws JsonProcessingException {

        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
        this.createdDate = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now());
        this.setComponentConfig(publishData.getComponentConfig());
//I tried changing to this
       //this.setComponentConfig(mapper.writeValueAsString(publishData.getComponentConfig()));
        this.setSystemStatus("Y");
        this.setStatus("Y");
        this.setSyncStatus(PENDING);
        this.setComponentName(publishData.getComponentName());
        this.setResource(RESOURCE_BRM);
        this.setCreatedDate(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        this.id = new CompositeKeyVrtSyncStatus(publishData.getComponentId(),publishData.getComponentType(), syncRequestV2);
        this.setModuleId(syncRequestV2.getModuleId());
        this.setVrtResolverType(RESOLVER_TYPE_BRM);
        this.setComponentVersion((double) publishData.getVersion());
        this.setAction(publishData.getAction());
        this.setCreatedBy(syncRequestV2.getLoginId());
        this.setModifiedBy(syncRequestV2.getLoginId());
        this.setHierarchyId(syncRequestV2.getRequestData().get(ACCESS_LEVEL_HIERARCHYID));
        this.setEnvId(syncRequestV2.getEnvId());
        this.deploymentHistoryDeploymentId = deploymentId.getDeploymentId();
        this.deploymentHistoryAppId = deploymentId.getAppId();
    }

 
    @PrePersist
    public void beforeSave() {
        this.setCreatedDate(myClass.getCurrentTimeStampObject());
    }




    @Override
    public String toString() {
       //conversion code
    }

    public DeploymentHistory getDeploymentHistory() {
        return deploymentHistory;
    }

    public void setDeploymentHistory(DeploymentHistory deploymentHistory) {
        this.deploymentHistory = deploymentHistory;
    }
}
======================================

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PublishData implements Serializable {
    private String orgId;
    private String appId;
    private String publishNotesId;
    private String branchId;
    private String componentName;
    private String componentId;
    private String componentType;
    private String module;
    private String action;
    private HashMap<String, Object> componentConfig;
    private Timestamp createdOn;
    private String createdBy;
    private String modifiedBy;
    private Timestamp modifiedOn;
    private Double changeLogVersion;
}

=========================================
  @Override
    public List<VrtConfigSyncStatus> saveDataToVrtConfigSyncStatus(Object list, TriggerSyncRequestV2 syncRequestV2, HistoryCompositeKey deploymentId) throws JsonProcessingException {
        List<VrtConfigSyncStatus> dataList = new LinkedList<>();
        List<BrmSyncData> brmSyncData = mapper.convertValue(list, new TypeReference<List<BrmSyncData>>() {
        });
        log.info("HistoryCompositeKey: deploymentId: {}, appId: {}", deploymentId.getDeploymentId(), deploymentId.getAppId());

        for (BrmSyncData dataForAM : brmSyncData) {
            VrtConfigSyncStatus vrtConfigSyncStatus = new VrtConfigSyncStatus(dataForAM, syncRequestV2, deploymentId);
            dataList.add(vrtConfigSyncStatus);
        }

        return vrtConfigSyncStatusRepo.saveAll(dataList);
     
    }`





When the function is executed to save all the data from the list I am getting classCastException .This code is working fine with java version 11
This is the stacktrace
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.util.HashMap and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatMapper.toString(JacksonJsonFormatMapper.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.JsonJdbcType.toString(JsonJdbcType.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType.access$000(AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType$1.doBind(AbstractPostgreSQLJsonPGObjectType.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.jdbc.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:61) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.JdbcValueBindingsImpl.lambda$beforeStatement$0(JdbcValueBindingsImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.spi.BindingGroup.forEachBinding(BindingGroup.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.JdbcValueBindingsImpl.beforeStatement(JdbcValueBindingsImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchImpl.lambda$addToBatch$0(BatchImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.PreparedStatementGroupSingleTable.forEachStatement(PreparedStatementGroupSingleTable.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchImpl.addToBatch(BatchImpl.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorSingleBatched.performBatchedOperations(MutationExecutorSingleBatched.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.AbstractMutationExecutor.execute(AbstractMutationExecutor.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2873) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:632) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:499) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1423) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1996) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:439) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.1.Final.jar!/:6.4.1.Final]
    ... 91 common frames omitted


Things I tried

return mapper.convertValue(vrtConfigSyncStatusRepo.saveAll(dataList), new TypeReference<List>() { });
`

